# Sqlite improve case-when and group by performance

Tags: sqlite, group-by, case-when

I'm optimizing my query using SQLite3.
There are some "CASE WHEN", "GROUP BY", "COUNT" functions.

BUT the query is VERY Slow (about 14sec)

Here is my database file information.

> 1. size: about 2GB
> 2. rows : about 3 millions
> 3. columns : 55 columns

What can i do for optimizing the query's performance?

Is there any better query for the result?

Please help me TT Thanks.

```
select
  case
    when score = 100 then 'A'
    when score < 100 and score >= 40 then 'B'
    else 'C'
  end as range,
  count(*) as count
from grade_info
where type < 9 and 
   (date >= '2019-07-09 00:00:00' and date <= '2019-07-09 23:59:59') and 
   is_new = 1
group by
  case
    when score = 100 then 'A'
    when score < 100 and score >= 40 then 'B'
    else 'C'
  end;
```

Table `grade_info` has multi-column index: `(type, date, is_new, score)`

The conditions for columns (type, date, is_new) are always used in this query. Here is the explain query plan result.

```
 selectid | order | from | detail
 --------------------------------
 0          0       0      SEARCH TABLE grade_info USING INDEX idx_03 (type<?) (~2777 rows) 
 0          0       0      USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY
```

and I want the result like this.

```
A | 5124
B | 124
C | 12354
```

Comment: Have you done an [Analyze](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html) recently?

Comment: You might also try [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](https://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) to gain some insight into how your indices are being used, etc.  BTW, are those separate indexes or is that one multi-column index?

Comment: I use multi-column index. and the conditions (type, date, is_new) are always used in this query.

Here is the explain query plan result.

selectid = 0
   order = 0
    from = 0
  detail = SEARCH TABLE grade_info USING INDEX idx_03 (type<?) (~2777 rows)

selectid = 0
   order = 0
    from = 0
  detail = USE TEMP B-TREE FOR GROUP BY

Comment: Stuff like that execution plan should go in the body of the question so it can be formatted legibly, btw.

Comment: A multi-column index can only be fully exploited when all but the right-most column is only used to test for equality. See https://www.sqlite.org/queryplanner.html#_multi_column_indices As you can see from that query plan, only the first column (`type`) is being used. I suspect an index on the date column would be more useful, but without knowing the distribution of your data, it's obviously hard to say for sure.

Comment: @Shawn  Thanks for pointing that out.  But in my tests, even though the query plan might list only a single column in the query plan, if the index contains multiple columns covering all referenced columns, it will also say "COVERING INDEX".  If I understand correctly, the initial lookup might only be able to use the listed query-plan condition, but having a COVERING INDEX will still allow all other conditions to be handled using only the index rather than going back to the table, so it is still beneficial to have a complete multi-column index. Does that seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- As Shawn suggests, try changing the index to have the `date` column as the first column:

  ```
  CREATE INDEX [idx_cover] ON [grade_info] ([date], [is_new], [type], [score]);
  ```
- sqlite allows reference to aliased expressions in the WHERE and GROUP BY clauses, so you can simply say `GROUP BY range` rather than repeating the CASE statement.  This probably won't change the efficiency, but makes the query shorter and more readable.
- If you run `ANALYZE` as MikeT suggests, the execution plan should change to say "COVERING INDEX...". If I understand correctly, that indicates that the entire query can be executed by traversing the single multi-column index without going back to the table data.
- Try date `BETWEEN '2019-07-09 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-09 23:59:59'`.
- Finally, CASE... WHEN is short-circuited, so make sure to place the more likely cases first so that it avoids unnecessary calculations. Also eliminate redundant conditional checks. If you have already checked a certain range in a previous condition, no need to re-evaluate that range in the next condition. (If you have already ruled out score = 100, then it is unnecessary to check score < 100 since it will of course be less than 100... assuming that all scores are ensured to be in the range 0 to 100) For instance, if scores are uniformly distributed, then the following could be faster, possibly eliminating +17000 conditional checks.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN score < 40 then 'C'
    WHEN score < 100 then 'B'  -- already tested to be >= 40
    ELSE 'A'                   -- already tested to be >= 100
  END AS range,
  count(*) AS count
FROM grade_info
WHERE type < 9 AND
      (date BETWEEN '2019-07-09 00:00:00' AND '2019-07-09 23:59:59') AND
      is_new = 1       
GROUP BY
  range;
```

Comment: Thank you for you awesome commnt. 
It was index ordering problem which i used.
I changed my index (ordering date, is_new, type, score)
Then changed after "group by" section and used "between" function.
Finally it was be very faster about 14 sec -> 1.5 sec!!

Thank you for your comment!